# Determining if a Type is for a descendent class

Tags: c#, reflection

I have Linq code that is enumerating all of the classes in an assembly and putting them into an array of `Type` objects, in order to pass it to an XML Serializer as the `AdditionalTypes` parameter.  I need to filter the contents of that array so it only contains classes that descend from a specific base class.

How do I determine from the `Type` object that the class is a descendant of the base class?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may be looking for [`Type.IsAssignableFrom`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isassignablefrom.aspx) or [`Type.IsSubclassOf`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.issubclassof.aspx). In both cases you need to think very carefully if generics come into play though, as the relationships become more complicated.

Comment: The `IsSubclassOf` method is what I needed.  There are no generics in the type tree at this time.

Answer (score 1):

something like this would probably get you where you need to be

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
                     .SelectMany(x => x.GetTypes())
                     .Where(x => typeof(MyBaseType).IsAssignableFrom(x))
                     .ToArray();
```